# How to add an SVG gradient to GIMP, in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, gimp

Given the recent trend of Facebook avatars incorporating the [rainbow flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag_(LGBT_movement)), to reflect the recent Supreme Court of The United States' [ruling that gay marriage is legal nationwide (in the US)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-33290341), I was trying to add such a gradient to GIMP (version 2.8).

The gradient:

[image]

was found at this page: https://openclipart.org/detail/220824/original-gay-pride-flag and is an SVG file, containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="400">
    <rect width="600" height="400" fill="#8e008e"/>
    <rect width="600" height="350" fill="#400098"/>
    <rect width="600" height="300" fill="#00c0c0"/>
    <rect width="600" height="250" fill="#008e00"/>
    <rect width="600" height="200" fill="#ff0"/>
    <rect width="600" height="150" fill="#ff8e00"/>
    <rect width="600" height="100" fill="#f00"/>
    <rect width="600" height="50" fill="#ff69b4"/>
</svg>
```

I placed this in the following directories, first:

```
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\gradients
```

And, secondly, in:

```
C:\Users\David\.gimp-2.8\gradients
```

I've refreshed the gradients (within the GIMP program), and closed – then reopened – the program.

Refreshing the gradients has produced the following error message in a pop-up alert-type window:

> Failed to load data:
>
> No linear gradients found in 'C:\Program Files\GIMP
>   2\share\gimp\2.0\gradients\Gay_flag_8.svg'

and:

> Failed to load data:
>
> No linear gradients found in
>   'C:\Users\David.gimp-2.8\gradients\Gay_flag_8.svg'

I'm – *clearly* – missing something, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, or not doing at all.

Following advice, from [gronostaj's answer](https://superuser.com/a/933935/5266), I've opened the SVG file in GIMP and, when offered the import options of:

> Import paths, and
>   Merge imported paths

I've checked both, and then saved the file – as a `.xcf` file – and then exported as a `.pat` file. This exported file was then placed in the appropriate directory:

> C:\Users\David.gimp-2.8\gradients\

With the file-name of `RainbowFlag.pat`.

I *then* tried to refresh the available gradients, which produces this error:

> **GIMP Message**
>
> Failed to load data:
>
> Fatal parse error in gradient file 'C:\Users\David.gimp-2.8\gradients\RainbowFlag.pat': Not a GIMP gradient file.

**tl;dr**: how do I add a new gradient, of SVG type, to GIMP 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

What you created there is not an SVG "gradient" - it is rather an SVG *image* with the rainbow colors.

SVG Gradents use the `<lineargradient>...</...>` XML element - there is a clear example of how to create one at: 
http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp  --
You can either convert your handcoded pattern to a SVG properly using 
`<lineargradient>`  and `<stop>` elements - or save a GIMP gradient file and edit that instead (since it is also a text based format). 
Just one more thing: beware that since you want hard color edges, you need two stops at each transition - for example,at the point 0.125, you need first a pink stop, to mark the end of pink, and follow it by a red stop, to mark the beginning of red.  (And that is why I'd say you are at least on the right track by trying to hand-edit the text definition of the gradient - this would be somewhat hard to come buy by using the U.I.)

Comment: While I was, definitely, beginning to realise that what I had was not an 'authentic' gradient - given the increasing complexity - I hadn't realised just how far from such it was. Thank you for your answer, I'll look into this presently. I would, however, ask that you improve your answer and don't rely on users following links to external sites. I know I have a low reputation here, but this advice is based on my experiences over at Stack Overflow, where I'm a little more familiar with the 'rules' (which I imagine are similar to those here).